# Install few .apk and setting other things

Tags: android

I have few (about 20) tablets and I want to install 3 different .apk not from market. Also I wanna change language on every device.
Is possible to automate this process? Any tips?

I thought about application which will "take" from folder all (3) different .apk and will install it in background(Can android do that?) and also will change language in settings.

Is it possible on android? I can use any permission.

Or maybe someone know better way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't want to install the apk files using debugging as it'll take a lot of time. Just thought of this idea. It may speed up your process.

Use Gmail. Mail all the three apks in one mail. Login to that email id from all the 20 tablets and just download and install the apps.

Change of device's language can be done using applications. You can make that.

Comment: I found nice code which should install .apk I'll try in weekend make it
https://gist.github.com/Fuzion24/2623253

And now I can also use ur idea about gmail I'll install one apk which should install rest .apk and set language :D